# Extjs 5.1 Event on a Ext.select. Cannot use addListener() on Ext.dom.Fly instances

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5, dom-events

I'm learning EXTjs. I was reviewing [this tutorial](http://mapfish.org/doc/tutorials/extjs.html#get-prepared-with-extjs) playing with hints from there.
When I've found that `Ext.select('p').on('click', paragraphClicked);` causes an error.

```
"[E] Ext.dom.Fly.addListener(): Cannot use addListener() on Ext.dom.Fly instances. Please use Ext.get() to retrieve an Ext.dom.Element instance instead."
{msg: "Cannot use addListener() on Ext.dom.Fly instances. Please use Ext.get() to retrieve an Ext.dom.Element instance instead.", sourceMethod: "addListener", sourceClass: "Ext.dom.Fly"}
```

I've made a [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/elennaro/btfpfhno/) where in console you can find this bug. And here are the sources:

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="myButton" value="My Button" />
<p>first paragraph</p>
<p class="myClass">second paragraph</p>
<p>third one</p>
```

JS:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
 var paragraphClicked = function(e) {
    Ext.get(e.target).highlight();
 };

 Ext.select('p').on('click', paragraphClicked);

});
```

Please, can you explain me what's wrong. And how should I bind an event to elements selected with Ext.select. It works with ExtJS 4, and does not work with 5. Consider I'm a novice in Ext.js. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error pretty much explains what's going on. You can't bind events to instances of the flyweight Element wrapper `Ext.dom.Fly`, because this is a lightweight object that gets reused, and is really only valid until the next call to things like `Ext.select`.

The reason this worked under ExtJS 4.2 is that the result of the `Ext.select()` call - an `Ext.dom.CompositeElementLite` instance - used to work with `Ext.dom.Element` classes. For performance reasons, in ExtJS 5, it now uses an `Ext.dom.Fly`.

Use `Ext.select('p', true)` instead; this will create instances of `Ext.dom.CompositeElement`, which doesn't use the flyweight version.